# returning more than one type from a function based on condition in java

Tags: java

Is there a way to  return more than one type from a function based on condition in java?

```
    /*here Object1 and Object2 are different objects created for 
    different classes*/
    public return_type function()
    {
        if(condition1)
            return Object1;
        else
            return Object2;
    }
```

Comment: You can just mention Object Class so you return any object. Now at this function where it was calling, you can check by instanceof and go further. This might help you

Answer (score 1):

You can create method return type `Object`. And check its return type and cast at run time.

```
public Object getValue(int i) {
    if (i == 1) return new Integer(1);
    else return new String("");
}

Object o = getValue(1);
if (o.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Integer.class)) {
    int result = (int) o;
} else if (o.getClass().isAssignableFrom(String.class)) {
    String result = (String) o;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use factory pattern.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm

You can return just Object, because in Java it is a base class of other classes. Or you can have a `GeneralInterface`, and both your classes implement it. Or it can be a base class.

```
class ObjectFactory {
     public GeneralInterface getObject() {
           //return object depending on your condition.
           if(condition1)
               return Object1;
           else
               return Object2;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Object type or if the Object1 and Object2 extends the same class or implements the same interface you could return the common parent. In the first case in the code invoking method you could use instanceof operator to determine which object type was returned.

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible if both Objects extend from a third class or implement an interface

```
interface DataInterface(){
  someMethodIfNeeded();
}
```

and then

```
class Object1 implements DataInterface{...}
```

But keep in mind that there are reasons why there exist two Objects, and not one